# .byte directive in 6502: Where it is stored

Tags: assembly, directive, 6502

A duplicate may be put on this question, but the particular questions with the same concept as mine have not been answered in one single way.

The `.byte` directive stores bytes into ROM unused by instructions. (the several questions with similar topics as mine had answers stating this) I have not been sure how to access the data from the `.byte` code, so let me give you an example of 6502 code.

```
.byte $0F
label:
    LDA label - 1
```

Would this work? Anyways, my question is not where the .byte goes (ROM), but how to access it. For example, in the NES the cartridge is loaded to `$8000`, so if I were to have `.byte` data at the beginning of my program, would I access it by loading from `$8000`? And when loading the next 16 bytes I would load from `$8010`?

Thank you, and please do not mark this as a duplicate as no other question answers my question.

If tl;dr, then, **How do you access the `.byte` data from ROM** (in the NES)

Comment: directives are assembler (the program that converts assembly language to machine code) specific.  No two assemblers have to conform to the same syntax nor rules.  So there is no one true answer to this question.  Also the one assembler you care about can certainly change how it works from one version to the next.

Comment: How memory is addressed is rather assembler specific. Some assemblers use just .org directive, other uses relocatable code which makes it more complicated, other uses non-contiguous segments of data/code. But basically, yeah your example will work, although typically you want to place label before data, not after it.

Comment: @user2537102                    

So for example, if I used `.org $8000`, which is also where the NES contains it's cartridge memory, would the `.byte` directives in the file with a `.org` of `$8000` could I access the bytes through the RAM starting at `$8000`?

Comment: Yes, a normal "simple" assembler will understand if you use .org $8000 that the data it assembles at the beginning of the file actually starts at adress $8000 in the CPU memory map. (typically in NES $8000 is ROM, not RAM, unless you use the Famicom Disk System or a special mapper). More advanced assemblers such as CA65 that can be used as a compiler back-end allow for more complex memory models, and in those case a `.org` directive is unfortunately not always enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a label on the `.byte` itself. For example, to load it into `A`, you could do

```
foo: 
    .byte $0F
    ; More stuff here
bar: 
    LDA foo
```

Comment: In my program, `.byte` loads 16 bytes at a time. How would I load that to an accumulator, or RAM?

Comment: If you have `foo: .byte $10 $20 $21`, then `foo` is the address of the `$10`, `foo + 1` is the address of the `$20`, and so on. If you have e.g. `X` set to 2, then `LDA foo, X` will load `$21` into `A`. So you could have a loop which does `LDA foo, X; STA target,X` while increasing `X`.